# How to deal with aspnetusers and my own users tables for Identity server 4?

Tags: asp.net, identity, identityserver4

My understanding is there are two functions for PasswordSignInAsync in SignInManager (sign in the user in using the user name and password): (1) verify the user name and password against the ones saved in the Aspnetusers table; (2) create sign in cookie.

I have my own user table, users. How to do combine the two tables? What are common practices?

Comment: It's really annoying, you pretty much have to override the SignInManager interface and a bunch of other stuff.  Check this [link](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity2.0-Custom-Database/)

Comment: Is there a sample I can read?

Comment: What's wrong with the link?  After you override the sign in manger include it in the IOC.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see the link. I will try to implement.

Comment: Not sure what the first alinea has to do with the question and why this question is tagged idsrv4. But I think my answer here may give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825825/how-to-correctly-implement-other-entitys-reference-to-identity-user/43829100#43829100

Comment: @user3097695 are you trying to use IDS4 or are you trying to use ASP.Net Core, because if you're using IDS4 then just link your tables and do your authentication seperately

Comment: I have asp.net core api server, Identity server 4 for authentication, and Angular 2/4 client as GUI.