# Can i add new custom tables inside my aspnet database inside asp.net MVC-5 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have the following:-

1. Visual Studio 2013.
2. i created a new asp.net MVC-5 web project.
3. the project is using asp.net identity 2.2.
4. for the authentication method i chose "Individual user accounts"
5. this process created a new database named `aspnet-OurProjectNanme-number`
6. inside the automatically generated database, i have a table named `AspNetUSers` which store the user info.

now i am working on building an ERP system. and inside the ERP system i want to add the following:-

1. a table named "Asset" to store the asset info.
2. the "Asset" table will have 2 columns named "`CreatedBy`" + "`ModifiedBy`" which should store the userId who created and modified the asset item.

now i am not sure how i need to achieve this? as i need to add a foreign key between my custom table "Asset" and the "AspNetUsers" table which have been created automatically.. **so can i add my custom table "Asset" inside the automatically generated database, and build the foreign key between the `Asset.CreatedBy` and `AspNetUsers.Id`** ??

- if the answer is **Yes** then can this relation break in the future if we want to upgrade our aspnet identity version ? as upgrading the identity might result in creating new tables or renaming existing ones etc.. which might break the relation between the Asset table and the AspNetUsers table?
- If the answer is No (i should not add custom tables inside the automatically generated database ) then how i can build the foreign key ?? and where i need to add the Asset table in this case??

Answer (score 4):

-- Update --

The answer is growing and growing and so is the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144276/discussion-between-ruard-van-elburg-and-john-g). I think I've shown all kinds of variations, which may not have helped to make it understandable. So here is a summary. For explanation, read the full answer and discussion.

Out of the box you have two contexts, identity and business. These are decoupled, so you can change your security without interfering with your business. This way, upgrading security won't break your application or other models. Since the contexts are seperate, changes to either one of them won't affect the other.

As a sidenote: you are not intended to directly access the AspNet identity tables. Implement the UserManager and use the avaiable methods of the manager to perform actions.

Now it comes to logic, where should information be stored? As a simple rule just ask yourself the question: is it part of security or business?

In both contexts you have users. For your requirement this is a logical 1:1 relation. But they are actually seperate. You can create people without supplying a login or delete a login, without deleting a user (people), e.g. for historical reasons.

All you want is to find all information for the current user. So all you need is the People.Id.

Without having to change the IdentityUser you can create the 1:1 relation by just overriding the AspNetUser.Id.

```
var appUser = new IdentityUser
{
    UserName = model.Email,
    Email = model.Email,
    Id = Convert.ToString(People.Id)
};
var identityResult = await userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, model.Password);
```

You do not need the identity context for your business. All you need is People.Id. The identity context is only used when tokens are issued and users are created / modified.

To obtain the id use something like this:

```
 var peopleId = int.Parse(Request.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Now you can query your business model using the Id.

When registering, extend the View and ViewModel with the People information you want to store. This will allow you to add both People and AspNetUser at the same time. Though this is not one transaction. But I think it is highly unlikely that creating either one would fail if you perform checks first.

You can validate the username and password (use the methods in the UserManager) and check the ModelState of the viewmodel before creating the user. Use attributes to force Required fields to be filled.

-- Original answer --

In order not to repeat myself, read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825825/how-to-correctly-implement-other-entitys-reference-to-identity-user/43829100#43829100).

In short, keep identity and business seperated.
Just in case the identity logic is removed from the same database, like when implementing IdentityServer.

It seems you have business information in AspNetUser. If so, create a Person table and move the information to that table. Relate to that table in your model. In table Person you can add a reference to AspNetUser.

-- update --

I think you understand correctly, but I will just add the details to this answer.

In most cases all tables are defined in one database. But that doesn't mean they are all part of the same model. There can be multiple contexts. In this case one for Identity and one (or more) for Business.

Now why seperate those two? The most important difference between the Business model and Identity model is that Identity tables are not to be called directly. We use the Owin context to call the UserManager / RoleManager.

That is why we cannot add these tables to the business model. Things can be altered in a way that is not secure. Also we do not want the business to have any knowledge about authorization. It shouldn't matter how this is done, as long as a user is identified and authorized.

Also you may want to implement OpenId and claim based authorization. In that case information doesn't have to be available in the database.

The idea is to create a 1:1 relation of the identity table AspNetUsers and business table People. There can be some redundancy, like email or (user)name. But that isn't a problem. The People table should contain all information you want to use in your business model. And the business tables should only relate to People, not AspNetUsers.

Now about the link between AspNetUsers and People. There are four options:

1. Set People.Id = AspNetUser.Id. Please note that AspNetUser.Id doesn't have to be a GUID. You can add your own value as key.
2. Set AspNetUser.Id = People.Id.
3. Add column AspNetUserId to People. No modifications to Identity are needed. You can add People to the Identity Model as well, but I don't think you can create both records in one transaction. You can use User.Identity.GetId() to get AspNetUser.Id. You may however ask yourself if the business should have knowledge about this information.
4. Add column PeopleId to AspNetUsers. You'll need to extend the IdentityUser to add PeopleId. An advantage is that you don't need the AspNetUser Id, but you can use the actual Id of People. When using OpenId or claims you can get People.Id from claims and you won't have to add AspNetUser.Id to the business. Optionally you can add People to the Model and as navigation property of the extended IdentityUser. When creating the user, you can do this in one transaction.

In case you are creating the user in seperate contexts, you'll need to handle the rollback yourself. But before adding a record to People, you can already test if an AspNetUser can be added: has a valid name/email and password.

Since your business model relates to the People table, you can query all assets and join with the People table for additional information. Or you can get all assets for the current user.

o yes, there are two contexts. The identity model, which contains the AspNet... tables + optionally People. And the business model, which contains all ERP tables + Asset + People.

You may consider to use code first for identity framework 2 and database first for the business model.

I hope that this helps. If not, let's continue in chat.

-- update --

The answer focused on seperation of domains: identity and business. That is why I didn't discuss one possible alternative concerning the AspNetUsers table.

The two models are representations of the database, which means that the database doesn't have to be an exact match. You are free to map tables and fields as you like, as long as they don't break database logic.

Since AspNetusers and People has a 1:1 relation and *when* both tables are present in the same database, you may as well merge the two into the AspNetUsers table. You can also add relations to the AspNetUsers table, though you may want to add an extra Id (int) column instead of using the current Id (string).

This does not mean the People class can be discarded, except that we have to change the table mapping: AspNetUsers.

Example:

```
[Table("AspNetUsers")]
public class People
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the sensitive fields are not mapped. We need however the Id field. You can now read and update the mapped fields.

You don't have to extend IdentityUser. You can add an AspNetUser and then update the fields using People in the other context. But if you want to add a user in one single transaction it may be easier to extend the IdentityUser (make sure you'll define the new fields in both People and ApplicationUser):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

There are multiple advantages:

1. There is only one transaction to add the user.
2. You cannot expose the sensitive fields since they are not mapped in People.
3. You cannot add People to the database, since some required fields are not mapped in People.

Please note that this may not work for all types of models (code first/database first + migrations).

Comment: so you mean i need to create a new table named Person. so when a new user register to my application, the user will have a record inside the AspNetUsers & inside the Person table.. is this correct ? so i need to modify the register bushiness logic to create a new record inside the person table ?is this correct? second question. where do i need to add the Person table ? inside the built-in database "aspnet-OurProjectNanme-number" which have been created for me? or i need to create a new database and add the Person table inside it ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to maintain AspNetUsers and Persons. So there is in fact a 1:1 relation. The Person table should be part of the same model as where Asset is defined, since you want to create a relation between the two tables.

Comment: so let me summarize the answer.. now i need to create a new database let say "MyCustomDB", add the Asset & Person tables to it... now when the user register inside the application, i need to create a record inside the Person table ?? and the person table will not have any relation with the AspNetUsers ??? if the answer is yes,, then the only issue i can see is that i will have two DBContexts so let say a user register correctly inside my application where a new user inside the AspNetUsers is created,,

Comment: and now when i try to create a new record inside the Person table something went wrong (such a the DB went down).. then in this case i will have inconsistent results is this correct? as i can not have a fully ATOMIC transaction between  2 separate DBs ??is this correct? or i face to face this pain ?

Comment: You do not need to create a new database, all tables can be stored in the same database. But the two have a seperate context. The IdentityContext and BusinessContext. And yes, you'll need to rollback yourself if something is wrong. But as long as all tables are in the same database, you can add Persons to the IdentityModel and extend IdentityUser with Person (creating a relation in the model, not the database), and so make it one transaction.

Comment: let me describe what i understand from you.now when i create my new project i will get a new DB named "aspnet-OurProjectNanme-number" with the models mapped to it. so now i can add 2 tables assets + people inside aspnet-OurProjectNanme-number DB, beside the existing tables. then i need to modify the registration business logic to create a new record inside the People table. before doing so i will create a new .edmx (since i am using DB first appraoch) and i will map my custom tables Assets,People and exclude the other tables..

Comment: .... so now i will have 2 contexts one for the identity and the other for the custom tables?? is this correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144276/discussion-between-ruard-van-elburg-and-john-g).

Answer (score 4):

The most common approach to what you want to do is simply to add your additional model as a DbSet in your `ApplicationDbContext`.

```
public class Asset
{
      public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

      public string UserId { get; set; }

      public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public IList<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbCotext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
     public DbSet<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
}
```

As I mentioned this is the most common approach as updating the Identity packages should have no impacting affects on your schema. That said you should always test updates before pushing to production.

UPDATE:
Note that when you're working with One to Many relationship's you will see in our Asset model a property for the User Id foreign key as well as the User object. Because of the relationship we are then able to create a `List<Asset>` in our User to complete the One to Many relationship. This will then allow us to directly query Assets belonging to a User.

As for Code First vs Database First the difference really comes down to how you define the mapping between Entity Framework and the Database.

As I mentioned below there is no one size fits all answer to should you separate the Identity context from your business context, or should you separate them into separate databases. The reality is that only you can answer that question for your needs. It is far more common to have all of the data in a single database. That said, there is something to be said for the security of having identifying information about a user such as their name, email and password hash separated from information like their address or payment information. The trade off is that you can find yourself trying to maintain objects that are supposed to be tied together but are only loosely related because they reside in different databases. Also you would then need to make sure you're using different users/passwords to connect to the different databases, and it's better to have the databases on different servers because if the server gets compromised you went through the entire exercise for nothing. The trade off to get the theoretical security ends up being so impractical with there consistently being another thing you have to do, that you end up seeing everything in one database where you can focus all of your hardening efforts.

Both the ApplicationDbContext and ApplicationUser objects should typically be created for you when you `File -> New` a project with Individual Authentication. You can add as many properties and relationships to your User as you require.

Comment: now to understand what do you mean exactly.. as i always work on the DB-First appraoch. So you mean i can add my custom tables such as the Asset inside the built-in DB which get created automatically for me `aspnet-OurProjectNanme-number` ,, Then i can create a new `.edmx` (context) which only contain my custom tables ?? so mainly all the tables the built-in ones + the custom ones will be inside the same DB ,, but i will have 2 context classes one contain the authentication tables while the other contain my custom tables ?

Comment: second question can you adivce more on the classes you provided? now you mentioned the following class `public class User : IdentityUser
{
     public IList<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
}` so what is the purpose of it exactly ?? and will there be any relation between the User and the Identity User inside the database level ?? foreign key or similar thing ? i mean when you define `public class User : IdentityUser`  how will this get translated inside the DB?  i know a new User table will be created ,, but will there be any FK between User & IdentityUser tables? at the DB level?

Comment: third question.. as mentioned on the other answer. is it more secure and reliable approach not to have a direct relation between the built-in authentication tables  such as `IdentityUser` and my application tables ? because let say when i show the Asset info on a view ,, then i will have the risk of having users exposing the authentication tables  since there is a direct relation between the tables?

Comment: ..the other answer suggest to have a People table which duplicate the IdentityUser info and inside this People table i can add all my custom properties and build the relation with my application tables such as the Asset table ?? so can you please advice on my above 3 questions??

Comment: Typically when you do `File -> New` you get a class `ApplicationDbContext` and `ApplicationUser`. I was shortening ApplicationUser to User. I know some people may argue their point of view and say their way is the right way. Really there is more than one way to do it and it really all depends on what your requirements are. If you have a requirement that your user db is a completely different db from your application's db then you might need to create a mapping object. What's more common in my experience is that the relationship is defined directly between models including the User.

Comment: so you are with extending the existing ApplicationUser class and add custom properties such as firstname,lastname,age, address, etc.. also it will contain a list<Asset> as a result of the one to many relation between the Asset and the applicationuser ?? so no need to create a People table ???  second question,, now i am doing all these changes to the model classes,, of course i need to manually update the related views and action methods to understand my custom properties (Firstname, age, address) ??

Comment: ... now i think this appraoch is more reliable.... and also i have noted that the automatically generated classes will mention that i can add extra properties to the existing applicationuser class .. this is mentioned inside the comments on the ApplicationUser classs ass follow:-  `// You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more. \\ `  so if Microsoft is providing these guidelines about extending the identity model ,, then i think there are not any risks of doing so...

Comment: Yes I would avoid the creation of the People table and just extend the properties I need in the ApplicationUser. I can't tell you what Views you need to update since that is purely up to you. That said it's rather pointless to add a bunch of properties if you don't have some way to View or update them. And yes as you mentioned Microsoft does give you some guidance to extend the class with your own properties.

Comment: now the only issue is that i prefer to work with DB-first appraoch rather than code-first. so i am not sure if i can still use DB-First in this case ? especially when dealing with the Assets and other ERP related tables. so let say i keep the identity tables to use code-first but for the ERP related tables to use dB-first. but not sure if in this case i can benefit from the FK relation between the ApplicationUser and the asset table since they will be inside 2 separate contexts. and one context is based on Code-First while the other is based on DB-First..

Comment: It's up to you whether you want one context or two, but you can use a single context with the Identity Models included and still do Database First. There is nothing stopping you from using the Identity tables with the Database First Approach. Database first just requires more setup on your part as you'll need to make sure that the mapping is correct between your models and the database. Code First just lets us be lazier by generating the SQL schema and mappings for us. I personally use Code First because I lack both a DBA and the time to deal with DB First.